# How to process multiple sheets of a workbook in datamapper of mule?

Tags: excel, mule, datamapper

I am trying to map a excel workbook file  which has multiple data in multiple sheets in MuleSoft datamapper. But getting no clue to work with.

Comment: kindly explain what you have done so far?

Comment: So far i have done with mapping of a excel file which has only one sheet in it. Now, I am trying to map the data of the excel which has multiple sheets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use libraries like apache POI to completely handle the conversion.

or

Split the worksheets into individual files and then process them through mule datamapper. Depending on the memory needs, you may have to consider streaming.